# A subspace of a metric space is normal

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it true that every subset $Y$ of a metric space $X$ is a normal topological space?

I think the answer is yes, because $Y$ is a metric subspace of $X$ equipped with the induced metric by the one of $X$.

Am I wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your argument is correct.  Every subspace of a metric space is itself a metric space and is therefore normal.

Comment: Is that sufficient?Does the OP assume metric spaces are normal or does that need to be proven first? I assumed in my reply this assumption needed to be proven and that it follows immediately from this that every nonempty subset of a metric space has an induced metric that makes it a topological subspace under the big metric's topology,yes? This has to be true unless there are subsets of a metric space that are non-metrizable-and I can't see how that can be possible,

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 That all metric spaces are normal is a standard theorem.  To prove it, first check that, for any closed set $A$, the distance function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous, and then use the open neighborhoods $\{x:d(x,A)<d(xB)\}$ and $\{x:d(x,A)>d(xB)\}$ to separate $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Ok,but it wasn't clear to me that this was assumed by the OP.The continuity of a metric on it's own generated topology for closed sets is pretty easy to prove as it pulls closed sets into closed sets.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I owe you an apology-I just found a counterexample of a non-compact Hausdorff space which isn't normal. My argument can be reworded strictly in terms of the distance function, but as it stands,it's not valid since it uses the Hausdorff condition to make the proof work.My bad.